# How to generate numbers until they are bigger than 10 000

Tags: c++, while-loop

```
    #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int num=1;
    while(num<10000)
    {
        num=num*3;
        cout<<num<<",";
    }
}
```

The last output is 19683, but it should be 6561. How should I change the condition?

Comment: `while(num<10000)` --> `while((num*3)<10000)`

Comment: `while (true) { num *= 3; if (num>10000) break; std::cout << num << ", "; }`

Answer (score 2):

With `num` being `6561`, condition `num < 10000` is still fulfilled and so the loop is entered once more.

Write...

```
int num=1;
do 
{
    cout<<num<<",";
    num=num*3;
}
while(num<10000);
```

such that the loop is left once `num` exceeds `10000`, and `cout` will not be executed any more for such a value. Note that `cout` and `num*=3` have been switched, so this loop also prints `1` (in contrast to yours). But I think it should print `1` as well, so that's why I dared to slightly change the semantics :-). Otherwise, you'd have to init `num` like `int num = 3`.

Answer (score 0):

Using `do-while` block:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  int num = 1;
  do {
    std::cout << num << " ";
  } while ((num *= 3) < 10000);
  return 0;
}
```

It will prints:

`1 3 9 27 81 243 729 2187 6561`

[Live](https://ideone.com/FTUMiQ).

Answer (score 0):

Make use of the fact that you can use the result of an assignment:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int num = 1;
    while((num *= 3) < 10000)
    {
        std::cout << num << '\n';
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
3
9
27
81
243
729
2187
6561
```

Answer (score 0):

Put cout before multiplication , program will first show a number which is less than 10000 and then multiplies num by 3.Thus 6561 will be shown and 6561*3>10000 so it exits the loop without printing 19683.